# Checking and comparing memory addresses for variables of different type

Tags: c, memory, nodes, lvalue

I am trying to compare the addresses of two variables in memory:

```
chunk_t *old_chunk, *new_chunk;

    if(&(old_chunk + 1 + old_chunk->size) == &new_chunk) { }
```

Here is the prototype for chunk_t:

```
typedef struct chunk_tag {
    struct chunk_tag *next; /* next node in list */
    int size; /* size of node in units, not bytes */
} chunk_t;
```

I get compiler errors on my if statement about "lvalue required as unary '&' operand".

I thought it was because I was adding an int old_chunk->size and a chunk_t old_chunk, so I typecase old_chunk->size as a chunk_t in the if statement, and the compiler told me "conversion to non-scalar type requested"

Comment: Should your new_chunk be declared like this? new_chunk or *new_chunk?

Comment: My fault, it was declared a pointer in the code, but I had a typo when I rewrote it. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to compare the addresses of the pointers to `chunk_t` objects, or addresses of the `chunk_t` objects themselves? There is a huge difference.

Comment: The addresses themselves. These are supposed to be nodes in a linked list, and I want to check if old_chunk occurs directly behind new_chunk in memory, so I can coalesce them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take an address of a computed value. Taking an address only works for a value that is already allocated somewhere on the stack.

Imagine saying "what is the address of the value that results from adding `1` and `2` together?" There is no address for that because it's a computed value. You need to have a variable, or a computed memory location, in order to be able to manipulate memory directly.

From what your code looks like, you want to do your address checking without the `&`:

```
if(old_chunk + 1 + old_chunk->size == new_chunk) { }
```

That is because both your variables are *pointers* to `chunk_t` objects.

Just make sure you know what you're doing. Adding `1` to `old_chunk` means looking `sizeof(chunk_t)` bytes later in memory, than where `old_chunk` points to. Conversely, adding `old_chunk->size` means looking `sizeof(chunk_t) * old_chunk->size` bytes later.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. both vars hold pointers though, so why wouldn't it be == new_chunk instead of == &new_chunk?

Comment: Because you had declared your variable wrongly, and later corrected your question :-)

Comment: That's great. I was wondering if adding old_chunk->size meant only adding integer*size bytes. That's what I want, to add sizeof(chunk_t)*size bytes. That is great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following expression

```
old_chunk + 1 + old_chunk->size
```

is not an lvalue, so you can't take its address with the `&` operator. This is what the compiler told you with the first error message.

The second error message tells you that you attempted invalid type conversion. It seems you did something like this:

```
(chunk_t) old_chunk->size
```

which is invalid if `size` is of primitive type.

Comment: hmm. So I should try saving that address as a variable and comparing with that instead?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `&(old_chunk + 1 + old_chunk->size)`.
Simply `old_chunk + 1 + old_chunk->size`.
Moreover it's better to check whether `old_chunk->size >= 0` because you've declared it as `int` in your struct.

P.S. It's not a 'prototype'. It is definition of the structure.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I have a question about integer addition though, if old_chunk is a chunk_t var and old_chunk->size is an integer, won't adding the integer just add the number of bytes in an integer*size instead of the number of bytes in an chunk_t*size?

Answer (score 0):

One thing is your declaration of new_chunk. It is declared as a chunk_t while old_chunk is declared as * chunk_t, a pointer to a chunk_t.

If you re-write your code as

```
    chunk_t * old_chunk, *new_chunk;

if((old_chunk + 1 + old_chunk->size) == new_chunk) { 
    printf("some message");
}
```

Then it will work. Or at least compile.